# How to show specific data in spinner with Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, spinner

My data is being retrieved, but I only want to display the names in my spinner like URL_xxx_NB or URL_xxx_FR, because I'm storing different URLs when people use the app in another language, and I need to retrieve only the names and when I put `datasnapshot.getvalue()` it brings me the whole thing, name + link. See below.

This is what I'm doing:

```
mDatabase.child("Users").child(uid).child("URL_ArchivosUsuario").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                final List<String> areas = new ArrayList<String>();
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    Log.e("UserUrls",""+dataSnapshot);

                        areas.add(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());


                    Spinner areaSpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                    ArrayAdapter<String> areasAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UserEdit.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, areas);
                    areasAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    areaSpinner.setAdapter(areasAdapter);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

My database structure:

[image: My database structure is the follow]

And this is what my spinner is showing:

[image]

I only want to see in my spinner the different URL_xxx_fr, nb etc names, and then I can manage when the user clicks in the different URLs to do something

Comment: Please add an existing url as an example and how you want to look in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, i just needed to getChildren and getKey, this is what i have done after `onDataChange`:

```
for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    String name = ds.getKey(); 
    areas.add(name);
}
```